# How to visualize spatial data using python

Tags: python, visualization, geospatial

Which libraries should I use for visualizing spatial data using python?

I have lat and lon positions of points, as well as the types of these positions:
I need to show all points on top of a map, and color points depending on its type.

I found [this tutorial](http://geoffboeing.com/2014/09/visualizing-summer-travels-part-6-projecting-spatial-data-python/), but it explains more complex things. I am looking for a simpler solution, if it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use matplotlib + [basemap](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/index.html) personally, I'm sure there are many alternatives but those always work for me.

Here's a simple example of putting a point on a map:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

map = Basemap(projection='ortho', 
              lat_0=0, lon_0=0)

map.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
map.fillcontinents(color='coral',lake_color='aqua')
map.drawcoastlines()

x, y = map(0, 0)

map.plot(x, y, marker='D',color='m')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you please advice some online tutorial on this combination?

Comment: There are good tutorials at www.pygis.io